# Remove blank space in a column created with LaTeX and fits its content

Tags: tables, align, columns, article, white-space

everybody. I am currently writing a paper and have been trying to resemble the table shown in figure 1 [image]

(it is a 1row- 3colum table), created with Microsoft Word. However, the table I obtain, created with the excel2latex add-in, is shown in figure 2 [image].

As seen, there is too much blank space in the columns and the content is not aligned nicely. I have tried to remove this blank space with no success though.

I attached the code for your reference.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

---

```
\documentclass[11pit]{article}

\usepackage{multirow} %To allow multirow

\usepackage{rotating} %To allow rotation from excel2latex

\usepackage{booktabs} %To allow top rule commands from excel2latex

\usepackage{tabularx} % Enable automatic line break in tables

\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet2'
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X l X}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{ARTICLE INFO} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ABSTRACT} \\

\tiny Article history:\\

\tiny Received October 00 0000\\
\tiny Received in revised form 0 November 000\\
\tiny Accepted 00 November 000\\

\tiny Keywords:\\

\tiny Word 1 \\
\tiny Word 2\\
\tiny Word 3\\
\tiny Word 4\\
\tiny Word 5&
      & 
\tiny The ozone layer is a layer in Earth's atmosphere which contains relatively high concentrations of ozone (O3). This layer absorbs 97-99\% of the sun's high frequency ultraviolet light, which is potentially damaging to life on earth. Over 90\% of ozone in earth's atmosphere is present here "Relatively high" means a few parts per million—much higher than the concentrations in the lower atmosphere but still small compared to the main components of the atmosphere. It is mainly located in the lower portion of the stratosphere from approximately 15 km to 35 km above Earth's surface, though the thickness varies seasonally and geographically. A Dobson unit is the most basic measure used in ozone research. One Dobson Unit (DU) is defined to be 0.01 mm thickness at STP (standard temperature and pressure). Ozone layer thickness is expressed in terms of Dobson units, which measure what its physical thickness would be if compressed in the Earth's atmosphere. In those terms, it's very thin indeed. A normal range is 300 to 500 Dobson units, which translates to an eighth of an inch-basically two stacked pennies. In space, it's best not to envision the ozone layer as a distinct, measurable band. Instead, think of it in terms of parts per million concentrations in the stratosphere (the layer six to 30 miles above the Earth's surface). A thinning ozone layer leads to a number of serious health risks for humans. It causes greater incidences of skin cancer and cataract of the eye, with children being particularly vulnerable. There are also serious impacts for biodiversity. Increased UV-B rays reduce levels of plankton in the oceans and subsequently diminish fish stocks. It can also have adverse effects on plant growth, thus reducing agricultural productivity. Another negative effect is the reduced lifespan of certain materials.   \\

\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}   

\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{center}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! The following is far from perfect, but IMHO a step in the right direction. I take that all the unnecessary `\multicolumns` come from the conversion program.

```
\documentclass[11pit]{article}

\usepackage{multirow} %To allow multirow

\usepackage{rotating} %To allow rotation from excel2latex

\usepackage{booktabs} %To allow top rule commands from excel2latex

\usepackage{tabularx} % Enable automatic line break in tables

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet2'
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[htbp]
{\tiny \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{5cm} X}
\toprule
ARTICLE INFO &  ABSTRACT \\
\makecell[lt]{Article history:\\
 Received October 00 0000\\
 Received in revised form 0 November 000\\
 Accepted 00 November 000\\
 Keywords:\\
 Word 1 \\
 Word 2\\
 Word 3\\
 Word 4\\
 Word 5}
      & 
The ozone layer is a layer in Earth's atmosphere which contains relatively high concentrations of ozone (O3). This layer absorbs 97-99\% of the sun's high frequency ultraviolet light, which is potentially damaging to life on earth. Over 90\% of ozone in earth's atmosphere is present here "Relatively high" means a few parts per million—much higher than the concentrations in the lower atmosphere but still small compared to the main components of the atmosphere. It is mainly located in the lower portion of the stratosphere from approximately 15 km to 35 km above Earth's surface, though the thickness varies seasonally and geographically. A Dobson unit is the most basic measure used in ozone research. One Dobson Unit (DU) is defined to be 0.01 mm thickness at STP (standard temperature and pressure). Ozone layer thickness is expressed in terms of Dobson units, which measure what its physical thickness would be if compressed in the Earth's atmosphere. In those terms, it's very thin indeed. A normal range is 300 to 500 Dobson units, which translates to an eighth of an inch-basically two stacked pennies. In space, it's best not to envision the ozone layer as a distinct, measurable band. Instead, think of it in terms of parts per million concentrations in the stratosphere (the layer six to 30 miles above the Earth's surface). A thinning ozone layer leads to a number of serious health risks for humans. It causes greater incidences of skin cancer and cataract of the eye, with children being particularly vulnerable. There are also serious impacts for biodiversity. Increased UV-B rays reduce levels of plankton in the oceans and subsequently diminish fish stocks. It can also have adverse effects on plant growth, thus reducing agricultural productivity. Another negative effect is the reduced lifespan of certain materials.   \\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{2-2}   

\end{tabularx}
}
\end{table}

\end{center}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]